# How I can load fixtures in all bundles or one specific bundle?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Latest version I use DoctrineFixtureBundle does not has `--Fixture=[path]` option in the command `doctrine:fixture:load` so how I can target specific fixture ?

Another problem I currently when I run the command `doctrine:fixture:load` it load fixtures from one bundle only so why other fixtures not loaded ?

here is the fixture that is not loaded (ignored)

```
<?php

namespace CarBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use CarBundle\Entity\Car;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\DependentFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class LoadCars extends Fixture implements DependentFixtureInterface
{

    /**
     * Load data fixtures with the passed EntityManager
     *
     * @param ObjectManager $manager
     */
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $car1 = new Car();
        $car1->setPrice(234);
        $car1->setYear(22344);
        $car1->setNavigation(true);
        $car1->setModel($this->getReference("X1"));
        $car1->setMake($this->getReference("BMW"));

        $car2 = new Car();
        $car2->setPrice(2122);
        $car2->setYear(2467);
        $car2->setNavigation(false);
        $car2->setModel($this->getReference("Passat"));
        $car2->setMake($this->getReference("VW"));

        $manager->persist($car1);
        $manager->persist($car2);
        $manager->flush();
    }

    /**
     * This method must return an array of fixtures classes
     * on which the implementing class depends on
     *
     * @return array
     */
    function getDependencies()
    {
        return array(
            LoadDictionary::class,
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I also need to trigger a specific fixture loader via `doctrine:fixture:load` command but it appears there is no such a command option anymore. (Symfony4.0.6, doctrine-fixture-bundle3.0). Did you find a solution?